# Groovy JSON convert to CSV

Tags: json, groovy, export-to-csv

I have a problem with parsing Json by JsonSlurper in groovy. Could you help?
my example json is:

```
{
   "expand": "schema,names",
   "startAt": 0,
   "maxResults": 50,
   "total": 21,
   "issues":    [
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217580",
         "self": "issue/217580",
         "key": "ART-4070",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Pre.3 Verification \"S\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217579",
         "self": "issue/217579",
         "key": "ART-4069",
         "fields": {"summary": "Verification \"C\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217577",
         "self": "issue/217577",
         "key": "ART-4068",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Enum type"}
      },
   ]
}
```

in a result I'm expecting a csv file with
list of key,summary only:

```
key,summary
ART-4070,#[ART] Pre.3 Verification \"S\"
ART-4069,Verification \"C\"
ART-4068,#[ART] Enum type
```

when I'm trying on a beginning of code parse this json I have an error:
Exception in thread "main" groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'S' with an int value of 83

The current character read is 'S' with an int value of 83
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'S' with an int value of 83
line number 13
index number 321
"fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Pre.3 Verification "S""}

code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = '''
{
   "expand": "schema,names",
   "startAt": 0,
   "maxResults": 50,
   "total": 21,
   "issues":    [
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217580",
         "self": "issue/217580",
         "key": "ART-4070",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Pre.3 Verification \"S\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217579",
         "self": "issue/217579",
         "key": "ART-4069",
         "fields": {"summary": "Verification \"C\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217577",
         "self": "issue/217577",
         "key": "ART-4068",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Enum type"}
      },
   ]
}
'''
def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText(json)
println obj
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You need double `\\` inside `'''` strings; second there is a `,`
on the last element of the list.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = '''
{
   "expand": "schema,names",
   "startAt": 0,
   "maxResults": 50,
   "total": 21,
   "issues":    [
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217580",
         "self": "issue/217580",
         "key": "ART-4070",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Pre.3 Verification \\"S\\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217579",
         "self": "issue/217579",
         "key": "ART-4069",
         "fields": {"summary": "Verification \\"C\\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217577",
         "self": "issue/217577",
         "key": "ART-4068",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Enum type"}
      }
   ]
}
'''
def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText(json)
println obj
```

Comment: I can't add double \\ cause it's a name of test case so it must be the same

Comment: This is a problem of your **example**. If you are entering the JSON as string in Groovy you **have to** quote `\` by `\\`. Your read JSON will have just a single `\` in it.

Comment: ok, how can I double // in a string before parsing it?

Comment: You don't. You **only need it if you type the JSON in your Groovy script**. You don't need to to add the \ if you are reading the JSON from a file (assuming the JSON is valid)